# Entangled event horizons

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, ads-cft, wormholes

Assuming it is possible in principle to entangle the degrees of freedom of the event horizons of two black holes, and that this is something that can be done, either after the black hole is formed, or only by careful preparation before collapse.

> **Question:** Could exist a physically realisable entanglement configuration of the horizons that behaves as a traversable wormhole,
>   in the sense that infalling information on one mouth becomes
>   non-thermal Hawking radiation on the other mouth, that preserves some
>   or all the original information?

A while ago I made a relevant [question regarding creating black holes with entangled light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48511/955). That method suggested there could provide two such entangled black holes